# Format date labels on x axis in MPAndroidChart

Tags: java, android, csv, mpandroidchart, axis-labels

**Background and Problem**

I´m trying to present a number of temperature values and dates logged in a CSV file in a line graph with the MPAndroidChart library. However I don´t fully understand how to format my date values on the X axis. I tried to use the IAxisValueFormatter but right now it only presents two values from my CSV file with a weird formatting (2609.03.14:09:12:25). The values in the CSV file looks like this: **"19.7 C,2017-12-09 12:59:43"** and so on. Since the Entry wants (float, float) to create an entry point maybe this is messing with the precision? Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

**Requirement**

I want all my entries to be presented in the line graph with the corresponding dates on the X axis pretty much as it is logged in the CSV file if this is possible.

**My onCreate method right now:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LineChart mLineChart;
InputStream inputStream;
String [] sensorData;
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLineChart = findViewById(R.id.linegraph);

    importData();

    LineDataSet dataSet = new LineDataSet(entries, "Temperatures");
    LineData lineData = new LineData(dataSet);
    mLineChart.setData(lineData);
    dataSet.setColor(Color.RED);
    dataSet.setDrawCircles(false);
    dataSet.setDrawValues(false);
    dataSet.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
    mLineChart.getDescription().setText("");
    mLineChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    mLineChart.invalidate();


    YAxis leftAxis = mLineChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMaximum(30f);


    YAxis rightAxis = mLineChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    rightAxis.setAxisMaximum(30f);

    XAxis xAxis = mLineChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(5);
    xAxis.setAxisMaximum(400f);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
    xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new DateAxisValueFormatter(null));
}
```

**My code for importing and creating entries:**

```
   public void importData() {

inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sensor_vardagsrum);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    try {
        String csvLine;

            while ((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            sensorData = csvLine.split(",");

            sensorData[0] = sensorData[0].substring(0, sensorData[0].length() - 1).replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            sensorData[1] = sensorData[1].replaceAll("\\D", "");

                    float temp = Float.parseFloat(sensorData[0]);
                    float date = Float.parseFloat(sensorData[1]);

                    entries.add(new Entry(date, temp));

                }

                System.out.println(entries);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Error in reading CSV file" + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**My IAxisValueFormatter:**

```
class DateAxisValueFormatter implements IAxisValueFormatter {
private String[] mValues;

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd:hh:mm:ss");

public DateAxisValueFormatter(String[] values) {
    this.mValues = values; }

    @Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    return sdf.format(new Date((long) value));
    }
}
```

**This is how the output looks right now:**

[image: Output]

Comment: I added a screenshot to show you how the X axis is drawn right now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you date is float value you need to make it back to Date so here don't pass null, but create new `IAxisValueFormatter` object and implement method `getFormattedValue` and here is my solution:

```
Date d = new Date(Float.valueOf(value).longValue());
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM", Locale.YOUR_REGION).format(d);
```

Hope it works for you!