# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: “2019-11-27”

Tags: java, android, json, date, date-parsing

In my app I am getting date from an API server as **String** value and I want to parse it to **int** but I get this error:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2019-11-27"
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java: 521)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java: 556)
```

I am trying to parse into an `int`. I want to pass it to `BarEntry` class constructor and it takes only int value or float new BarEntry(int or float values,float). I need it for showing Chart.

> My Activity

```java
try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    Log.d("Response", response.toString());
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string());
    JSONObject rates = object.getJSONObject("rates");
    Iterator < String > iterator = rates.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String keyDate = iterator.next(); // this date which i want to parse to int value
        String cad = rates.getJSONObject(keyDate).getString("CAD");
        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String value = String.format("%.4s", cad);
        float value1 = Float.parseFloat(value);
        int date = Integer.parseInt(keyDate);
        Log.d("TAG", date + "");
        //Log.d("TAG", value1 + "");

        //barEntries.add(new BarEntry(keyDate, value1));

    }
} catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("ChartActivity", e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Well evidently your string is `"2019-11-27"`, which is not parsable to an int. What would you like to do with it?

Comment: @khelwood because i want to pass it to BarEntry class constructor and it takes only 
int value or float 
new BarEntry(int or float values,float); 
i need it for showing Chart

Comment: I suggest `Math.toIntExact(LocalDate.parse("2019-11-27").toEpochDay())`. The example yields 18227, an `int` that you can comfortably pass to the `BarEntry` constructor.

Comment: @OleV.V. your suggestion requires API level 24 and mine is 19.Is there other way?

Comment: `LocalDate` is part of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, which is built-in from API level 26. However, it has also been backported. So you can use it on API level 19 if you add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project and make sure you import `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate`. See [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project) for a very thorough explanation.

Comment: @OleV.V. It's good idea but 2nd problem is `Math.toIntExact()` requires API 24

Comment: Uh oh, I wasn’t aware of that one, sorry. You may simply cast: `(int) LocalDate.parse("2019-11-27").toEpochDay()`. And/or code a range check yourself before casting. You may also cast to `float` instead, then you need no range check.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you finally i got the date in `int` value but the yields is **18227**.
Is it possible to convert it to normal date?

Comment: @OleV.V. I had converted this value **18227** to normal date and it gives date of this year **1970/01/01** and in JSON  it's  **2019-11-27** why? and how should i correct it?

Comment: You're getting the epoch day, you wouldn't pass days to the constructor for date, as it takes milliseconds if my memory serves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### LocalDate and ThreeTenABP

```
    String dateString = "2019-11-27";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString);
    int epochDay = (int) date.toEpochDay();

    System.out.println(epochDay);
```

This snippet outputs:

> 18227

The documentation explains:

> The Epoch Day count is a simple incrementing count of days where day 0
>   is 1970-01-01 (ISO).

So my suggestion is that this number is fine for feeding into your `BarEntry` constructor.

`toEpochDay()` returns a `long`. If your constructor doesn’t accept a `long`, convert to `int`. In the code above I did a simple cast. The risk is that we will get a very wrong result in case of `int` overflow for dates in the far future or the far past. I prefer to do a range check to avoid that:

```
    long epochDayLong = date.toEpochDay();
    if (epochDayLong < Integer.MIN_VALUE || epochDayLong > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Date " + date + " is out of range");
    }
    int epochDay = (int) epochDayLong;
```

The result is the same as before. This check is the same check that the `Math.toIntExact` method I mentioned in a comment does (available from Android API level 24).

> I had converted this value **18227** to normal date and it gives date
>   of this year **1970/01/01** and in JSON it's **2019-11-27** why? and
>   how should i correct it?

Let me guess, you effectively did `new Date(18227)`. My suggestion is that you avoid the `Date` class completely and stick to java.time, the modern Java date and time API. Why you got 1970 is: 18227 is a count of *days* since the epoch, and `Date` counts *milliseconds* (since 00:00 UTC on the epoch day). So you got 00:00:18.227 UTC on that day. We already have a `LocalDate` in the above code, so just use that.

```
    System.out.println(date);
```

> 2019-11-27

Should you need to convert the opposite way, it’s easy when you know how:

```
    LocalDate convertedBack = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(epochDay);
```

The result is a `LocalDate` with the same value.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Documentation of `LocalDate.toEpochDay()`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/LocalDate.html#toEpochDay())
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help,I accepted your answer,and  i have another question in my account,could you please help me with that? i will paste the link here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306683/is-it-possible-to-show-a-chart-by-using-mpandroid-from-web-server-api]

Comment: Thank you, @MohammedQadah. I’m afraid I won’t be able to help with that other one. In any case I will take a closer look when I find the time.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much,i will wait